# Getting data from AngularFirestore from HTML to the TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my first Angular-Firestore project. What I want to do is to get data from the HTML page which I insert to a list of data using an *ngFor. When I press the submit button on a form. Some data has to be input by the user and some are coming from that *ngFor loop. The issue is it throws the following error : *SellinglistComponent.html:53 ERROR Error: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field ownerID)*

But when I press the submit button again(Pressed Twice) it works with no issue and I can see data is being sent to the database. What would be the case for this? Please help me to solve it. Thank you.

TypeScript file is as follows

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { PaginationService } from '../pagination.service';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sellinglist',
  templateUrl: './sellinglist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sellinglist.component.scss']
})

export class SellinglistComponent implements OnInit 
{
  bidObjectId : string;
  panelOpenState = false;
  public show: boolean;
  public bidName : any;
  bidPrice : number;
  bidAmount : number;
  userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<{}>;
  ownerID : any;

  constructor(public page1: PaginationService, private db: AngularFirestore) {}

  public openDialog(): void 
  {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }

  ngOnInit() 
  { 
    //iterate through all the saleCrop object using pagination service for more info, refer pagination service component
    this.show = false;
    this.page1.init('saleCrops','postDate', { reverse: true, prepend: false});
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var userID = user.uid;
    this.userRef = this.db.doc('users/'+userID);
    this.userRef.ref.get()
    .then((doc) => {
      //checks if the user is logged in and copies their first and last names to the a varible to be used later in the DB
      if(doc.exists) {
        console.log("hello")
        this.bidName = doc.data().fname+" "+doc.data().lname;
      }
      else{
        console.error("No user logged in!");
      }
    })
    console.log(this.bidName)
    
  }

  //Handling the infinite scroll in the marketplace 
  scrollHandler(e) 
  {
    if (e === 'bottom') {
      this.page1.paginate('backward');
    }
  }

  addBid(bidObj)
  {  
    this.bidObjectId = bidObj;
    console.log(bidObj)
    this.db.collection('saleCrops').doc(this.bidObjectId).ref.get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log(doc.data())
        this.ownerID = doc.data().posterID;
        console.log(1)
        console.log(this.ownerID)
        console.log(2)
      }
      else{
        console.log("error");
      }
    });
    this.db.collection("bids").add({
      bidderName : this.bidName,
      accepted : false,
      bidPrice : this.bidPrice,
      bidAmount : this.bidAmount,
      bidDate : new Date(),
      bidderID : this.userRef.ref,
      objectID : this.bidObjectId,
      ownerID : this.ownerID,
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("Bid added Successfully");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error Doc: ", error);
    });
  }
}
```

HTML file is as follows

```html
<mat-card *ngFor="let saleCrops of page1.data | async">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="example-small-box">
        <img src="{{ saleCrops.photoURL }}" style="object-fit: cover; height: 150px; width: 150px; border-radius: 50%">
    </div>
    <div class="example-small-box">
        <h2 class="">
          <br>
          {{ saleCrops.itemName }}<br/><font size="5">{{ saleCrops.itemAmount }}kg</font><br/><small>Rs. {{ saleCrops.unitPrice }} per 1kg</small>
        </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
    <mat-accordion>
      <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
      (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title></mat-panel-title>
          <mat-panel-description>
            Click For More Details
          </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="example-very-small-box">
            <strong style="font-size: medium">Poster Details</strong> 
            <br><strong>Name</strong> : {{ saleCrops.posterName }}
            <br><strong>Region</strong> : {{ saleCrops.posterRegion }}
            <br>Member Since {{ saleCrops.posterJoinDate.toDate() | date: 'yyyy' }}
          </div>
          <div class="divider"></div>
          <div class="example-long-small-box">
            <div class="description-box"><strong style="font-size: medium">Description</strong> 
              <br><p>
                {{ saleCrops.itemDescription }}
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="desc-space-box"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="example-very-small-box">
            <strong style="font-size: medium">Current Bid</strong>
            <br><p>Bid Amount : 
            <br>Bidding Price :</p>
            
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-md-row">
          <button style="width: 120px;" class="btn btn-primary">Contact Seller</button>
          <div class="divider"></div>
          <button style="width: 120px;" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="openDialog()">Place Bid</button>
          <div class="divider"></div>
          <button style="width: 120px;" class="btn btn-danger">Report Seller</button>
        </div>
        <div class="bid-box" *ngIf="show">
          <form (ngSubmit)="addBid(bidObj.value)">
            <input type="text" #bidObj name="bidObjID" [(ngModel)]="saleCrops.doc.id" class="form-control" value="saleCrops.doc.id"  disabled>
            <h6>Bidding Price (in Rupees per kg)</h6>
            <input type="number" name="bidPrice" [(ngModel)]="bidPrice" class="form-control" style="width: 200px">
            <h6>Bidding Amount (in kg)</h6>
            <input type="number" name="bidAmount" [(ngModel)]="bidAmount" class="form-control" style="width: 200px">
            <button class="submit" style="width: 120px;" class="btn btn-primary">Add Bid</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
</mat-card>
<p *ngIf="page1.done | async">I ran out of stuff to show!</p>
<app-loading-spinner *ngIf="page1.loading"></app-loading-spinner>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasoning as to why you're getting `SellinglistComponent.html:53 ERROR Error: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field ownerID)` is because the function you're calling is asynchronous.

By the time you call `this.db.collection("bids").add({})`, `this.db.collection('saleCrops').doc(this.bidObjectId).ref.get()` still hasn't returned a response. Which is why the second time you call it, `this.ownerId` is set.

You can test this by calling `console.log(this.ownerId)` just before `this.db.collection("bids").add({})`

To provide a solution, You must make the function asynchronous.

`async addBid(bidObj)`

Then you can call the following with await.

`await this.db.collection('saleCrops').doc(this.bidObjectId).ref.get()`

Since the two block of codes look dependent on each other. You can do the following.

Instead of setting `this.ownerID = doc.data().posterID;`

You can return that value like so.

```
    await this.db.collection('saleCrops').doc(this.bidObjectId).ref.get()
        .then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                return doc.data().posterID;
            }
        }).then(id => {
            this.db.collection("bids").add({})
        }).catch(error => console.error(error));
```